# Настройка monit для мониторинга PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, monit

Настраиваю monit для мониторинга PostgreSQL:

```
check process postgresql with pidfile /var/run/postgresql/12-main.pid 
start program = "/bin/systemctl postgresql start" 
stop program = "/bin/systemctl postgresql stop" 
if failed 
port 5432 
protocol pgsql username "monit" password "123456" database "test" 
then alert
```

Жалуется она на строчку:
protocol pgsql username "monit" password "123456" database "test". Конкретно на username,говорит, что такой синтаксис неправильный.
я менял на user, другие кавычки ставил. но воз и ныне там.

Comment: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#:~:text=To%20allow%20access%20to%20Monit%20for%20testing%20purposes%2C%20one%20can%20create%20an%20account%20and%20allow%20access%20for%20example%20like%20this

Comment: в документации на писано, что вы должны 1) создать учетную запись 2) дать ей права доступа. сделали?

Comment: сделал. она жалуется на синтаксис, не на права доступа